# invalid form key for ajax call in magento admin panel

Tags: forms, magento, key

I have a list of record with delete button. After clicking the delete button one function is fired and there I call a ajax jquery. But it is showing invalid form key.
My code is like:

```
var form_key  =  '<?php echo Mage::getUrl("*/*/delete/key/".Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey());?>';
            $.ajax({
                    url: form_key+'?isAjax=true',
                    data: {'producttypeId': producttypeId},
                    type: "post",
                    success: function() {
                        $('#data-table').load();
                        $('.messages').hide();
                        $('.custom_message').show();
                        //$('#row_' + producttypeId).fadeOut('slow');
                    }
                });
```

Please help me why this is showing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also I have made changes in php.ini file based on http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/71679/#t389219 url. Specially I enabled max_input_vars and increasing  post_max_size to 10M. But still no result.

Comment: anybody is there? please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you calling your javascript with jQuery `.live()`, or `.on()`? Depending on how you use it, those methods can prevent the javascript from sending correctly. You need to initiate your javascript using one of the following:

```
jQuery('document').ready(function() {});
jQuery('window').load(function() {});
```

Then you can use `.live()` or `.on()` to bind to an **event**, such as *click*:

```
jQuery( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {
    alert( jQuery( this ).text() );
});
```

Hope that helps!